# multiple websites on magento 2 with the same title on google

Tags: magento2, title, meta-title

I have an issue on my multiple websites magento 2 :
 I have different domain each one has its own theme,default page..., but on google seach the both websites show the same title( the title of cms page of the first website)
Help